# Palindrome function returns true when word isn't a palindrome

Tags: javascript, palindrome

Could someone be kind enough to tell me why "almostomla" returns true in my code.

I have searched and have seen there are simpler versions but im so deep into this code now i need to make it work if at all possible.
Please excuse the terrible variable names, i was frustrated.

```
function palindrome(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  str = str.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/g, '');

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length / 2; i++) {
    for (var j = str.length - 1; j > str.length / 2 - 1; j--) {
      var iDntKnow = str.charAt(i);
      var iDntKnowEither = str.charAt(j);
      if (iDntKnow === iDntKnowEither) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Appreciate all answers.

Comment: Because you have it return `true` as soon as it finds a matching character in each position. `almostomla` starts and ends with an `a` so it immediately returns true. Instead, you need to adjust your loops and only return true if no difference are found.

Comment: "javascript palindrome" isn't a question

Comment: Possible duplicate of one of these +2500 other  [palindrome questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/palindrome?sort=newest&pagesize=50)

Answer (score 3):

While I can understand the frustration of wanting to make something work if you have put time into it, there is also something to be said for starting from the drawing board and not driving yourself crazy. The main problem I see with your code is that you have two loops when you only need one. The second loop is actually sabotaging you. I would suggest running a debugger (type "debugger" into your code and run) to see why.

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish:

```
var palindrome = function(str) {

  // Put any additional string preprocessing here.

  for(var i = 0; i < str.length/2; i++) {
    var j = str.length-i-1;

    if (str[i] != str[j]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

In this way you are comparing each mirrored element in the string to confirm if the string is a palindrome.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be answered by now.

If performance isn't an issue, why not just use this?

```
function palindrome(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  return (str.split().reverse().join() === str)
}
```

It splits the string into an array, reverses that and joins it back together. The result is compared to the original string.

Answer (score 1):

You can only know if it's NOT a palindrome in each iteration.

Also, why using nested loops?

```
function palindrome(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  str = str.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/g, '');

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length / 2; i++) {
      if (str.charAt(i) !== str.charAt(str.length - i - 1)) {
        return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
 function palindrome(string) {
   string = string.toLowerCase();

   for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(str.length/2); i++) {
     var character1 = string.charAt(i);
     var character2 = string.charAt(string.length-1-i);
     if (character1 !== character2) {
        return false;
     }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The double for loop means you're going to compare the 1st character to every other character instead of comparing the first to the last then the 2nd to the 2nd to last, etc.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please vote it back up, because my solution works.

Comment: I didn't downvote you and it still won't work because `ceil` isn't a function. I believe you mean `Math.ceil`. I'd suggest testing your code in your console before posting it.

Comment: I did test it. Sorry. I forgot I have a library that most people don't have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that omits spaces and commas:

```
var removeLetterFromString = function(string,letterPos){
    var returnString = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        if(i!==letterPos){
             returnString=returnString+string.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return returnString;
};
var palindrome = function(string) {
    string = string.toLowerCase();
    var stringCheck="";
    var recheck = true;
    while(recheck){
        recheck=false;
        for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i ++){
            if(string.charAt(i)===" "||string.charAt(i)===","){
                string=removeLetterFromString(string,i);
            }
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i ++){
            if(string.charAt(i)===" "||string.charAt(i)===","){
                recheck=true;
            }
        }
    }    
    if(string.length===0){
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(string.length/2); i++) {
        var j = string.length-1-i;
        var character1 = string.charAt(i);
        var character2 = string.charAt(j);
        if (character1 !== character2) {
             return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```